# Full Join diff left + right joint

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, full-outer-join

If I have 2 Tables: T1 and T2 and I do something like this:

```
select ISNULL(T1.Name, T2.Name) AS Name
from T1
FULL JOIN T2 ON T1.Product = T2.Product
```

And this join:

```
select ISNULL(ISNULL(T1.Name, T2.Name),T3.Name) AS Name
from T1
Left JOIN T2 ON T1.Product = T2.Product
Right JOIN T2 T3 ON T1.Product = T3.Product
```

They are same or some cases are different?

Comment: ISNULL doesn't take three arguments

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: *"They are same or some cases are different?"* Why not run the code you have, and find out? I can tell you, however, that the queries are *not* the same from a processing perspective.

Comment: @Larnu I take same results, but maybe I am wrong

Answer (score 3):

Both queries do not produce the same results.

The first query returns all names from both tables. The second query only return names that are in `t2`, because of the final `right join`.

Consider this simple dataset:

```
insert into t1 (name, product) values ('foo1', 'bar'), ('baz1', 'zoo1');
insert into t2 (name, product) values ('foo2', 'bar'), ('baz2', 'zoo2');
```

Both tables have one product in common, and one product on their own.

The first query correctly returns `foo1`, `baz1` and `baz2`, while the second query returns just `foo1` and `baz2`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=22674f3a9465e3d494d1887e4304dfb5)**

Unrelated note: in general, use `coalesce()` instead of `isnull()`; that's standard SQL, and it accepts more than two arguments.